# Linux Mint: How to prevent Slack from re-inserting its key to apt-key

Tags: linux, linux-mint, gpg, apt-key

Since `apt-key` is now deprecated, I have exported and copied all of my package keys to the gpg folder and updated the corresponding `/sources.list.d/*` accordingly by adding the `[signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/<relevent_key_file>.gpg]` field.

However, after every reboot, something is effectively undoing this change for Slack by re-adding its key to apt-key and deleting the `signed-by` from its `/sources.list.d/slack.list`. I know this because when I perform `$ sudo apt-get update`, I see the following output:

> W:
> https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease:
> Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg),
> see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.

This forces me to re-do all of my work. How do I stop either Slack, or whatever process responsible, from doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing this myself, it's indeed annoying. I didn't find a perfect solution, but I did find a workaround: make the `slack.list` repo file (after adding `signed-by` entry to it) immutable:

```
sudo chattr +i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/slack.list
```

The biggest inconvenience here is that `add-apt-repository` fails with an error due to this immutability:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
PPA publishes dbgsym, you may need to include 'main/debug' component
Repository: 'deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/ lunar main'
Description:
Toolchain test builds; see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ToolChain

More info: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-test-lunar.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-test-lunar.list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 362, in <module>
    sys.exit(0 if addaptrepo.main() else 1)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 355, in main
    shortcut.add()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuthandler.py", line 221, in add
    self.add_source()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuthandler.py", line 307, in add_source
    sourceslist.save()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/extendedsourceslist.py", line 391, in save
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/slack.list'
```

So if you have such an error, just make `slack.list` mutable again, run `add-apt-repository`, and back to immutable:

```
sudo chattr -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/slack.list
sudo add-apt-repositor <smth>
sudo chattr +i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/slack.list
```